# Altium remove radius on unused layer on through holes in a multilayer board

Tags: altium

I have a high density through hole part on a 8 layer board. Each through hole has a radius of copper on each layer. Is there a way to tell Altium that I don't need this radius on layers that don't have anything connected to them. This would allow me to reduce the number of layer for the PCB because I could route around through holes on certain layers while maintaining minimum clearance. Please see the attached picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term you're looking for is "annular ring".

Unconnected pads are removed on output generation, by default (see Gerber output, Layers tab, "Include unconnected mid-layer pads" unchecked).

It sounds like you need this feature at design-time rather than on output, so as to better take advantage of the available clearance.

To do this, set the pad stack type to Top-Mid-Bottom and reduce the middle dimensions.  Note you will have to manually place pads or circles on the layers which still connect.  This cannot be done by rule, as far as I know.  Alternately, you can use Full Pad Stack and specify each layer's pad size individually, but this is probably even harder to maintain and check.

Warning: you probably should not reduce annulus to zero.  The annulus still serves the purpose of increasing clearance to the hole.  Honor your fab's mid-layer alignment plus drill tolerances: these errors dictate the minimum distance between hole and nearby copper, and standard electrical clearance (whatever that is, maybe 4 to 8 mils) plus removed (unused
/ unconnected) annulus is one way to implement that.  Alternately, set clearance relative to hole diameter rather than pad OD (although I'm not sure offhand you can do this directly?).

It's a hacky solution for a hacky situation; use it carefully, check diligently (ensure used pads have adequate annulus), and preferably avoid it altogether (choose a fab process with finer tolerances or more layers, or an IC with fewer pins or wider pitch).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to visit the "properties" of the pad or via in question, then select the "stack" sub-menu and chose "full-stack" to display the details for each layer. If you're not connecting to anything on a particular layer then make the x/y size on that layer the same as the hole size. This should make your annular copper section disappear on that layer. Test it out to see if this is what you require.